# Upgrade laptop processor

Tags: cpu

I have a 3 month old Dell inspirion 15 3521 laptop with a core i3 CPU.
I want to upgrade it to i5 or i7 whichever suits.

Is it possible to upgrade the CPU?
Wat are the other parts can I upgrade?

Comment: What specific CPU do you have?  I will link to a random i3 and i5 to make my comment.  i5: http://ark.intel.com/products/75989/ i3: http://ark.intel.com/products/75033/ while they are similar they are not compatible with one another.  There is also the fact there is 1168 pins you would have to solder perfectly in order to remove and install a new part.  Once you post what part you have I can provide an answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

Looks to me like the CPU is soldered onto that board, meaning unless you really want to take a major risk - you're unable to do so.  A [dell forum](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19506017.aspx) suggests that as does looking through the [owner's manual](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-15-3521_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf)

Other parts you can upgrade to get more responsiveness would be RAM and HDD or SSD.  Usually a move to an SSD (assuming you don't have one) is the most noticeable upgrade for people.

Answer (score 1):

Most laptops cannot be upgraded easily, except for a few very specific components (often just the RAM and mass storage options, and sometimes not even these). In particular, components like the CPU are usually soldered straight onto the motherboard. Laptop manufacturers do this partly because it is cheaper to mass-produce, but that is not the only reason: upgradeable sockets make the board bigger and heavier, and laptops cannot be *too* big and heavy, or people will complain.

Technically it is possible to remove and replace components that are soldered right onto a motherboard, but it is an *extremely* difficult process, and you risk ruining the motherboard if you get it wrong. You would also need to replace each component with one that is drop-in compatible with the old one, and I'm not sure that the chips you're referencing are compatible in that way. It would be easier to replace the whole motherboard, but this is more expensive, and it only works if somebody makes a motherboard in the right size and shape to fit into your laptop case.

In other words, I don't think you can upgrade your laptop in the way you've asked about. Others have suggested upgrading your RAM or replacing your HDD with an SDD, and these may be better options for making the machine faster.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to upgrade to an i5 per say, but this requires buying a new mobo with i5 installed on it. Look at ebay (So, you cannot just go get a new CPU and install it).

There is only one access panel so any other upgrades are relatively easy:

HDD to SSD

Add more RAM (OS Permitting, specs say Windows 8 64 bit)

Change optical drive for a HDD/SSD caddy (add another drive)